# Proposition 4.12 from Blackburn, de Rijke and Venema's "Modal Logic"

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I'm trying to prove Proposition 4.12 from Blackburn, de Rijke and Venema's "Modal Logic" (page 196). The proposition is as follows:

> *A logic $\Lambda$ is strongly complete with respect to a class of structures S iff every $\Lambda$-consistent set of formulas is satisfiable in some $\mathfrak{S} \in S$.
> A logic $\Lambda$ is weakly complete with respect to a class of structures S iff every $\Lambda$-consistent formula is satisfiable in some $\mathfrak{S} \in S$*

As weak completeness follows from strong completeness, only the proof for strong completeness matters. The authors present a proof from the right to left case of strong completeness by contraposition, which is as follows:

> Suppose $\Lambda$ is not strongly complete with respect to S. Thus, there is a set of formulas $\Gamma \cup \{\varphi\}$ such that $\Gamma \Vdash_S \varphi$ but $\Gamma \nvdash_\Lambda \varphi$. Then $\Gamma \cup \{\neg \varphi\}$ is $\Lambda$-consistent, but is not satisfiable on any structure in S.

Which I found to not be particularly hard, however, the left to right direction has left me stumped. I tried a direct proof, but could not find any way to relate completeness and satisfiability. Similarly for a proof by contraposition.

I feel like I'm missing some rather obvious detail, but after nearly an entire day of trying to prove this, I don't see what I could be missing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again by contraposition.

Assume that there is $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \}$ that is $\Lambda \text {-cons}$ but not satisfiable.

Being not sat we have: $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \} \vDash \bot$; but $\Lambda \text {-cons}$ means: $\Gamma \cup \{ \phi \} \nvdash \bot$, and thus the logic in not *strongly complete*.

Comment: Thank you! I suspected the proof had something related to deriving $\bot$, however I completely blanked the fact that $\Gamma$ being unsat meant that it could derive $\bot$.